# PHP Undefined index :sales

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Array

```
 "incomes" => array:2 [
    "sales" => array:1 [
      0 => array:4 [
        "id" => 8
        "code" => "501000"
        "name" => "Sales"
        "net_movement" => 340708.37
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I'm trying to get `net_movement` value

Code

```
foreach($pnl as $row)
{
    $sale_income = $row['sales'][0]['net_movement'];
    Debugbar::addMessage($sale_income,'income');
}
```

The `Debugbar` already printed the value correclty but why I still getting this error?

Comment: If that is all then you don't need a loop.  What is repeating?

Comment: Maybe is not defined on second iteration

Comment: I am guessing not all rows in `$pnl` has 'sales' index

Comment: Can you make a var_dump($pnl); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you need to loop `sales`:

```
foreach($pnl['incomes']['sales'] as $row)
{
    $sale_income = $row['net_movement'];
    Debugbar::addMessage($sale_income,'income');
}
```

If there is only ever `0` then just:

```
$sale_income = $pnl['incomes']['sales'][0]['net_movement'];
```

Comment: Thanks.It worked. But could you explain why my code will face the error?

Comment: Yea, you completely missed the `incomes` array in the multi level array

Comment: Because you loop the main array and `incomes` and something else that is there and there is no `sales` except under `incomes`.